# Background HTML listener

Tags: javascript, python, html

on gmail, once in a while, on this specific line, the "Qm jU Ln" changes to "Qm Ln Q".

Is it possible to detect/track that change in the HTML in the background? Would this require a plugin?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C1E02.png)

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [GreaseMonkey](https://www.greasespot.net/) or [TamperMonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/) to run custom JS on the page and then either have it check for the class every so often with a [setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp), or watch for the change with [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver).

Comment: do you know how I can code it in JS? I can look it up if you tell me what its called. Eventlistener?

Comment: The easier way would be to use `setInterval()`.  There's no event.  You're just creating a timer that looks for an element with that class.  With jQuery, it would be something like: `if ($('.Qm.Ln.Q')[0]) { /*do something*/ }`.  In vanilla JS, you'd use something like: `if (document.querySelector('.Qm.Ln.Q') !== null) { /*do somethng*/ }`.